# Jmeter-Maven Integration : Azure Backend Listener Issue : Want to integrate my jmeter tool with Azure using MAVEN

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

2023-01-10 01:10:24,612 ERROR o.a.j.v.b.BackendListener: StandardJMeterEngine@27a0a5a2-Backend Listener Exception initialising: io.github.adrianmo.jmeter.backendlistener.azure.AzureBackendClient

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.adrianmo.jmeter.backendlistener.azure.AzureBackendClient

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the next lines to your [pom.xml file](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) in order to include the plugin into [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath):

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterExtensions>
        <artifact>io.github.adrianmo:jmeter.backendlistener.azure:0.2.8</artifact>
    </jmeterExtensions>
</configuration>
```

Full pom.xml just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>io.github.adrianmo:jmeter.backendlistener.azure:0.2.8</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

More information:

- [Adding Excluding libraries to from the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-Excluding-libraries-to-from-the-classpath#adding-jars-to-the-libext-directory)
- [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)